# Calling Mips from C

Tags: c, assembly, mips

**I'd like to call assembly (specifically MIPS) code from my C program and call the C back from the assembly**.
I've decided on the GNU GCC as my compiler, (I am also guessing I need an emulator?)
I'm on a x86 Win 7 machine.
There are some things that are very unclear to me how this can/should work out.

- If MIPS will be using a load-store archi with 32 regs and the C will continue to use a register memory archi because I'm on x86?
- Now that I want to call mips assembly instead of x86 assembly, can/do I still use asm() ?
- If MIPS uses more registers than C, will I be able to access those registers from my C code?

Can anyone help me out with this, perhaps by pointing out where I could learn this bit of sorcery?

Thanks

Disclaimer: I am working on a verification of self modifying code project for credit in school, and this code is going to be used as an example, but I am not getting any credit for this code.

Comment: Have you chosen a compiler already? Calling conventions are going to be compiler-specific.

Comment: How complex is the MIPS code? Will it call system calls? If not, an emulator for it is much easier to write. You'll have to figure out the tough details of passing data back and forth between the emulator and your C code...

Comment: I'm going to use the GNU GCC as my compiler

The MIPS will only call functions from my c program - no system calls.

Comment: Is your C code going to be compiled using a MIPS cross-compiler? I'm afraid I may have misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common MIPS calling convention is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS).  The easiest way to write a C-callable assembly routine is to write a skeleton for the routine in C, and then copy the assembly code output from the compiler into your assembly source (use gcc's `-S` option).  Say you want to call an assembler function defined in `C` as `int foo(int a, int b)`. You would write a simple version of that function in `C`. For example, put the following into foo.c:

```
int foo(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;  // some simple code to access all arguments and the return value
}
```

Then you would compile that function using a MIPS cross compiler (see below) using the `-S` and the `-O0` option to gcc which will produce a text output file `foo.S` giving you MIPS assembler source code to access the arguments for function `foo` and showing you where to put the return value.  Simply copy that source file into your own assembler source, and add the assembler calculations you need to compute `foo`.

Calling C from assembly is straightforward once you have calling in the other direction figured out.

You can download a free MIPS gcc [cross compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) tool chain from [Mentor Graphics](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/) (formerly Codesourcery).

You can download a free, fully functional (it boots and runs Linux) MIPS simulator from [here](http://www.ovpworld.org/download_MIPS.php). Don't use SPIM or MARS, since they do not completely model the MIPS architecture.

Comment: I figured that would be the MIPS calling con, I was wondering, what the C calling con would be. The part I don't understand is if C would still be running on x86 and if so, where those registers map to (tho I suppose that would be easy enough to look up). (Essentially, I'm asking if C can be used with a load store archi)

I'll look up those links, Thanks!
But I didn't quite understand your first paragraph... If I'm calling mips code, do I still use asm() ?

Comment: To do what you are proposing, you will need to use the gcc toolchain I mentioned above to cross-compile your C program and your MIPS asm program into a MIPS binary and then run it on the MIPS simulator, or real MIPS hardware. The cross-compiler runs on your x86 computer, but the resultant binary will only run on a MIPS simulator or a MIPS computer. It will not run on an x86.

Comment: added a bit more detail into the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it now; I'll check these out.

Comment: Could you also please tell me if it's possible to access the 32 mips registers from my C code (for example, set $s0 to 0 from C) or will I have to jump in asm and then jump back? I tried looking at the cross compiler documentation, but I can't seem to access it.

Comment: It isn't possible to access the registers from C code, nor is it necessary. The compiler will put the arguments in the correct registers when it compiles a call to a function, and your C source code doesn't need to do anything special.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you mean. Thanks very much again!

Comment: 'It isn't possible to access the registers from C code' - why not? This should be possible using inline assembly, if all this code is Mips compiled C/Mips assembly. I agree that it's unneccesary - just should be possible is all.

Comment: More precisely, it is not possible to reliably and repeatably predict how the C compiler will allocate C variables to registers. So while it is technically possible to access the registers from inline assembly within C code, it is not useful to do so. This refers to accessing registers by register name, such as `$s0`, or `$t4`. However inline asm does allow you to write code like `mov %[foo], %[bar]` where `foo` and `bar` are C variables and the compiler will then substitute the register names where foo and bar were placed by the compiler